# Python constructor overloading with zero arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x

There are many SO QAs and other articles about how to create multiple constructors.
But I couldn't find how to achieve what I'm looking for,

Consider the below methods, the requirement is to create `__init__` with zero args and creds args, so at initialization it will return session based on arguments.
Since that is not possible, a `classmethod` is introduced to initialize the instance with creds as shown below. But as you can see, it will not work.

```
@classmethod
def with_keys(cls, access_key, secret_key):
    """
    Initialize boto3 session based on key and secret.
    """
    # Initialize variables and session <= How to do this?
    # self._access_key = access_key
    # self._secret_key = secret_key
    # self._session = boto3.Session(
    #     aws_access_key_id=self._access_key,
    #     aws_secret_access_key=self._secret_key,
    # )
    return cls() # <= this will overwrite the session

def __init__(self):
    """
    Initialize boto3 session based on IAM Role.
    """
    self._access_key = None
    self._secret_key = None
    self._session = boto3.Session()
```

of course, I can achieve this the other way as shown below. But is it possible to do it without providing args to `__init__`?

```
@classmethod
def default(cls):
    """
    Initialize boto3 session based on IAM Role/Default Credentials
    """
    return cls(None, None)

def __init__(self, access_key=None, secret_key=None):
    """
    Initialize boto3 session based key and secret.
    """
    self._access_key = access_key
    self._secret_key = secret_key
    if access_key == None:
        self._session = boto3.Session()
    else:
        self._session = boto3.Session(
            aws_access_key_id=self._access_key,
            aws_secret_access_key=self._secret_key,
        )
```

Comment: I mean, it is *possible* but you should almost certainly be creating a constructor that accepts those arguments. In any case, you just want `instance = cls()` then modify the instance as you want,then return the instance.

Comment: So note, you could just do `self = cls()` at the top then uncomment the rest of that code,  and use `return self` as the return statement, although, using `self` would be a confusing variable name here.